# How to integrate API amember pro into ionic 5 application

Tags: rest, cordova, ionic5, amember

Currently I am developing a new application using API amember pro for an already website. I want to integrate the API into my app (ionic 5) and I am really new about this.

For now, I have developed in half way progress and I am using the list of API under Remote API Permissions. The problem is, all the API used are needed to be login again in app just like opening website in application. May I ask about how to identify the suitable API in amember pro to be used in Application?

Hopefully there will be someone who have experienced this and willingly to share this with me huhu. Thank you.

The docs for API amember is here; https://docs.amember.com/docs/REST